# Material ui Accordion Summary Text color change on Expand

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I have a material UI accordion and when I expand the accordion, I want to change the color of the accordion summary text.

```
     <Accordion expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')} className={classes.root}>
    <AccordionSummary
      expandIcon={expanded === 'panel1'?<RemoveIcon style={{color:'#008b8c'}} />:<AddIcon style={{color:'#008b8c'}}/>}
      aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
      id="panel1bh-header"
      className={classes.accordionSummary}

      IconButtonProps={{
        edge: 'start'
      }}
    >
      <Typography className={classes.heading}>

          
        
       <b>Hi</b> 
</Typography>
    </AccordionSummary>
    <AccordionDetails>
      Sample
    </AccordionDetails>
  </Accordion>
```

I want to change the color of hi to green on expanding.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a running example ? With code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Create another style for the color of the expanded text.  Then use a ternary operator to decide it based on the expanded boolean.

```
 <Typography className={expanded === 'panel1' ? classes.expandedText : classes.heading}>
```